# Function recommendation?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I want the general form of a function $f(x)$ containing two other variables $a, b$

such that the graph of the function resembles the image below:

[image: A graph of the desired function]

The function should satisfy the following conditions:
$$f(0)=1$$
$$f(\frac{4}{5}b)=c$$
$$f(b)=0$$

Piece-wise defined functions are acceptable.

Comment: Do you mean $b,c$ instead of $a,b$ in your first sentence? In any case, you can start with any function that has the right general shape (for example, [the function $-\tan^{-1}(x) / (1 + x^2)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-+arctan(x)+%2F+(1%2Bx%5E2))) and apply rescaling and translation (both in the $x$ and $y$ variables) to get the desired graph.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is to fit some modification of $f(x) = x \mathrm{e}^{-x}$. For example the following is a plot of $f(-(x-5))= -(x-5) \mathrm{e}^{x-5}$ on $[0,~5]$:

[image]

This fits the general shape quite well, has a maximum at $x=4$. As for your concavity, your data really only looks concave up for $(0,~3b/5)$ and concave down for $(3b/5, ~b)$---note that a local max more or less requires negative local concavity. The above graph has an inflection point at $x=3$, which again seems to fit with your data.